# Android Date picker dialog to select next 10 year date only

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-datepicker

Android `DatePicker` `dialog` to select next `10 year date` only.

I have datepicker dialog in which I want to select only `future date` (next 10 year) and prevent to select past date. 
Below is my code which avoid to select past date but I want to show only next 10 year date too.

```
try {
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy", Locale.US);
    edtMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year+2, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            edtMonth.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    // it is used for prevent old date selection.
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()+2);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To Display only 10 year from Today you have to set your `MinDate` to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and set `MaxDate` to `CureentTimeMillis + Next 10 Year Millis` and add this value to your `MaxDate` like below way.

To `setMinDate`  Today.

```
  datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To `setMaxDate` Today.

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 year Millis);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.setTime(new Date());
     cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
     Date newDate = cal.getTime();
     datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
     datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(newDate.getTime());
```